# vb.net: clearing all contents of string array

Tags: vb.net

i have this:

```
    Dim split As String() = temp_string.Split(",")

    ''#feed all info into global variables
    patient_id = split(0)
    doc_name = split(1)
    lot__no = split(2)
    patient_name = split(3)
```

how do i clear all the contents of split() ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Array.Clear(split, 0, split.Length)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
ReDim split(-1)
```

Comment: why is your method better than the two below

Comment: The different in the three methods:

    redim split(-1)
This leaves the array as a string array with zero elements.

    Array.Clear(split, 0, split.Length)
This leaves the array with all it's elements assigned a value of nothing.

    split = nothing
This leaves split assigned a value of nothing.

Which is better? It depends, but sometimes it makes a difference. For example, if you later use ubound to find the upper bound of split, you will get 0, 3, or an error for these three cases.

Answer (score 5):

No need to do anything. The garbage collector will do its jobs clearing the variable. Explicitly set every variable to nothing will slow down your application.

Answer (score 4):

You can always set it to `Nothing` which will clear the reference. Then the garbage collector will take care of the rest when it finds that to be a good idea.

```
split = Nothing
```

However, if this is a local variable of a method you would typically not need to worry about this, the array will be available for garbage collection as soon as it goes out of scope.

Comment: why is your method better than the one below? you are just saying split=nothing?

Comment: I would assume that after `Array.Clear`, split will still hold a reference to the (now cleared) array. In my sample it will not reference anything. I would say that in most normal cases the difference will not be noticable (I assume that split is a local variable in a method that goes out of scope when the method is done).

Comment: +1 for "not need to worry about this"  There is no good reason to set it to Nothing unless the array itself is a global variable, and that's unlikely.